# Ассоциативные контейнеры в с++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! У меня возникла следующая проблема, не могу подобрать контейнер для хранения переменных и их значений. К слову, map подходил почти идеально, но он сортирует элементы, что для меня совершенно не подходит. Я пишу парсер математических выражений и использую поиск по имени переменной, чтобы получить ее значение. Было бы идеально, если бы существовал контейнер наподобие map который не сортируется автоматически (то есть контейнер по типу ключ->значение, но без автоматической сортировки). Я уже себе всю голову поломал, и на ум приходят только костыли. Какие могут быть решения?

Comment: Непонятно, чем вам сортировка может помешать?... Ну, возьмите `unordered_map`...

Comment: Поиск и сортировка - столпы информатики, которые идут рука об руку и помогают друг другу. В заранее отсортированном контейнере гораздо проще осуществлять поиск, более того, его довольно таки дешево поддерживать отсортированным. Такие дела.

Comment: @Harry, функцию хеширования автор на какой полочке возьмет?

Comment: Я экстрасенсорно прозреваю, что компилятор автора вежливо посылает писать компаратор. А в случае с unordered будет посылать писать хэш

Comment: @gbg, типом ключа для данного вопроса будет являтся строка, поэтому не нужно будет определять ничего.

Comment: О, тогда, учитывая, что строка хэшируется в size_t, на 32 битной машине автор рискует словить грабли крайне интересной формы и фактуры, когда у него хэши наедут. На 64 битной тоже, но с меньшей вероятностью.

В данном вопросе, мы торжественно помогаем автору решить проблему молотка и микроскопа

Эй, афтор! Ознакомьтесь https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/Что-такое-Ошибка-молотка-или-Ошибка-xy

Comment: @gbg Для строки? из стандартной библиотеки :)

Comment: @gbg,   " В заранее отсортированном контейнере гораздо проще осуществлять поиск"?..  Сложность поиска для  map  -    O(log n),  а  для  unordered_map  константная.  Что  проще?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan - константная она если повезет, может оказаться и линейной. А что с коллизиями будем делать?

Comment: неплохая шутка в сторону разработчиков std::unordered_map .  Что будет быстрее, зависит от количества элементов, в любом случаи преимущество  std::unordered_map для этого вопроса, благодаря вам, я добавлю в ответ

Comment: @ARHovsepyan разработчики-то тут причем? Хэш таблица работает за константное время (кстати, а какое? В случае с обычным мапом из миллиарда строк log_2(миллиард)=30, довольно неплохая константа). А если нам не повезет и хэши много-много раз понаедут, начнется интересное дело с линейным поиском внутри отдельных бакетов. Линейный поиск по строкам - это так себе удовольствие.

Comment: Я еще раз спрашиваю автора вопроса - почему он не желает сортировать элементы? Сколько можно решать проблему молотка?!

Comment: @ gbg, не нужно комментарии превращать в дискуссию, но все же я хочу обратить внимание читателей на то обстоятельство, что   log_2(миллиард)=30 означает вызов функции, которая не зависит от количества элементов,  до 30  раз, а хэш функция такая же  не зависящая от количества элементов функция, ну а стандартная хэш  не медленне, чем  функция  поиска по высоте дерева map.  И вызывается она для поиска ключа  всего один раз.  Ну не стоит говорить что 1 < 30...  Ошибаюсь я или нет,  решать  вам, но дискуссировать дальше не стои...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75708/discussion-between-gbg-and-ar-hovsepyan).

Answer (score 1):

`unordered_map` больше подойдет, как уже заметил пользователь`Harry` 
 Для хранения имен переменных и их значений  использование  `map` не  совсем логично, поскольку вам не нужно сортировать имена  переменных по лексикографическому порядку. Какая переменная появляется раньше другой, не должен зависить от  того, какое имя она имеет.
Если вам нужен какой то порядок, то нужно брать другой контейнер, поскольку поиск в `unordered_map` осуществляется по возвращенному значению хэш функции, а в данном контейнере, для каждого ключа это значение уникально, и проверяется ключ 
только на равенство.

Для определенного порядка, вы можете брать любой контейнер с типом элементов `std::pair<std::string, double >`.

Для примера:

```
using P = std::pair<std::string, double >;
std::vector<P> vp;
vp.emplace_back(make_pair("s", 1));
vp.emplace_back(make_pair("d", 2.1));
vp.emplace_back(make_pair("f", 3.2));
vp.emplace_back(make_pair("g", 5.6));
for (auto& p : vp)
    cout << p.first <<'\t' << p.second <<'\n';
```

Вы можете использовать любой из данных

```
cout << vp[1].first <<'\t' << vp[1].second;
```

Comment: Хорошо, но unordered_map тоже сортирует элементы. И тогда вопрос такой, как восстановить исходный порядок вводимых переменных, чтобы при установке интератора в начало контейнера он выдавал значения в том порядке, в котором они были введены ?

Comment: Во первых  unordered_map не сортирует элементы,  чтоб убедится просто берите альфавит и по очереди вводите с каким то значением.  Но а если вам  нужен  определенный порядок вывода, то  нужно об этом писать в самом вопросе. Тогда  не было бы лишных разговоров...

Comment: @Dmitry Vlasov: А так вам значит надо, чтобы сохранялся порядок создания элементов? Почему тогда эта информация отсутствует в тексте вопроса?

Comment: @AnT,  давно вас не было...

Comment: @DmitryVlasov заведите таблицу индексов: имя переменной -> индекс в контейнере значений (`std::unordered_map<std::string, int>;`), а сами значения храние в векторе например, как предлагают в ответе выше. У вас получится что-то вроде такого:

`vp[indexTable[variableName]]`. Только придётся следить за выходом за пределы вектора.